# Loop para Repetir Nomes

Tags: vba, loop, excel-vba

Prezada comunidade,

Acredito que seja simples a solução mais, estou tentando fazer a seguinte regra de negocio:

Tenho uma relação de nomes em uma Plan1, preciso que o nome de cada um deles se repita por 12x cada na Plan2, tenho um codigo que consegue repetir o primeiro nome, mas não estou conseguinto incremetar meu valor.

```html
Sub RODAR()


Dim num As Integer
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wss As Worksheet
Dim nome As String

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = Sheets("Plan1")
Set wss = Sheets("Plan3")

nome = 1

For cont = 2 To 13

wss.Select
nome = Cells(2, 2)

ws.Select
Cells(cont, 2).Value = nome

nome = nome

Next
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Muito obrigado Evert,

Segue solução da questão levantada acima:

Lembrando que tive tanto ajuda do Sr. Evert, como do Sr. Anderson

```html
Sub RODAR()
    
    Dim num As Integer
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wss As Worksheet
    Dim nome As String
    Dim linha As Long
    Dim linha2 As Long
    
    
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = Sheets("Plan1")
    Set wss = Sheets("Plan3")
    
    
    nome = 1
    linha = 2
    linha2 = 2
    
    While wss.Cells(linha, 2) <> ""
    While ws.Cells(linha2, 2) <> ""
    linha2 = linha2 + 1
    Wend
        For cont = linha2 To linha2 + 11
        nome = wss.Cells(linha, 2)
        ws.Cells(cont, 2).Value = nome
        Next cont
        
        linha = linha + 1
    Wend
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Não precisa da variavel `wb` que não está sendo utilizada, nem da `nome`, que pode ser simplificado usando `ws.Cells(cont, 2).Value = wss.Cells(linha, 2)` e a fórmula que postei, tive oportunidade de testar e está funcionando, creio que poderia tentar refazer seus _loops_ para usar apenas 2 ao invés de 3 _loops_, isso diminui consumo de recursos do computador e otimiza tempo.

Answer (score 1):

Precisaria incrementar seu *loop* com algumas informações, segue um pequeno modelo que fiz (não pude testar...) mas para ver a lógica:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim wsORIGEM As Worksheet
Dim wsDESTINO As Worksheet
Dim NOMES As Variant
Dim NOME As Variant

Set wsORIGEM = Sheets("Plan1")
Set wsDESTINO = Sheets("Plan2")

NOMES = wsORIGEM.Range("A1:A3").Value

For Each NOME In NOMES
    j = j + 1
    For i = 1 To 12
        If j = 1 Then
            wsDESTINO.Cells(i, 1).Value = NOME
        Else
            wsDESTINO.Cells(i + (12 * (j - 1)), 1).Value = NOME
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Acho que dá pra limpar bem esse *loop* e essas variáveis, contudo, fiz em cima do seu código apenas para **funcionar**, mas confesso que ficou bem "feio" meu código ai... desculpe-me por issso.

Comment: Tranquilo Evert, a logica esta boa, mas o código não funcionou mesmo, vou ter que revisar, mas muito obrigadoo :)

Comment: Qual foi o erro? E em qual linha? No caso ai veja que nome diz: `NOMES = wsORIGEM.Range("A1:A3").Value` é a matriz onde contém os nomes na planilha `Plan1`... de A1 até A3... e vai colar sempre na Planilha `Plan2` começando da primeira linha da coluna A. Creio que o que precisa adaptar para funcionar seria apenas isso ai...